# Resize background image depending of a viewport size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to bootstrap. I have simple page with a header (which has background image) and logo.

I have two questions

1. How to hide background image of the header tag and center the logo if <768px
2. How to resize the background image depending of the viewport size?

Here's the code I have

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
  <header>
     <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
   </header>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body header {
  position: relative;
  width: 940px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(../images/header-bgr.png) no-repeat;
}
body header img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}
```

Comment: media queries - google this and you'll get loads of info on this

Comment: I know about media queries but I thought there is a bootstrap 3 wrapper or something to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

**For hiding background image of the header tag and center the logo:**
CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

body header {
  position: relative;
  width: 940px;
  height: 200px;
  background: none;
  margin:0 auto;
}
body header img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  display: none;
}

}
```

**try `background-size:contain;` for resizing your image**

```
body header {
  position: relative;
  width: 940px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(../images/header-bgr.png) no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always clearer if you provide jsfiddle or codepen with your actual code.

When you already have a container class on top, you don't really have to define another header with static width. Either it can be 100% or use container class on header. Your structure can basically be reduced to this form.

HTML:

```
<header class="container">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://cdn4.colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/02/Olympic-logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="logo">
  </figure>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 0;


  figure {
    max-width: 200px;
    margin: 0px auto; 
    position: relative;
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    & {
      background: none;
      min-height: auto;

      figure {
        img {
          margin-top: 00%;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/gorkhali/pen/azjVev